# Google Spreadsheet URL with Query Does not support callback?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to develop an application where I am going to fetch data from Google Spreadsheet on some conditions. I use following URL to fetch data. The data comes in JSON and it work perfectly if I am entering the URL in address bar.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?tqx=out:json&tq=select%20*%20%20where%20B%20%3D%20%27&KEY=MY_SPREADSHEET_KEY
```

When I am going to fetch it from JavaScript using callback (JSONP) it does it receive data.

```
var resource = document.createElement('script'); 
resource.type = 'text/javascript'; 
resource.async = true;
var spreadsheetkey = "MY_SPREADSHEET_KEY";
var url="http://www.example.com";
resource.src = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?tqx=out:json&tq=select%20*%20%20where%20B%20%3D%20%27"+url+"%27&key="+spreadsheetkey+"&format=json&callback=getReply";
var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);

function getReply(data){
alert(data);
}
```

I am not getting any alert which I supposed to. Can anybody tell me what might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For *unauthenticated* calls to the spreadsheet feed you need to make your spreadsheet public.

Comment: Yes even though I have marked it as public, still it doesn't give me the result. I think it's a bug in Google Docs. Because if you are appending query in URL then the response comes in JSON string not as JSON object.